# OSM_id missing from ways table created by Osm2pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

GIS newbie here so excuse my ignorance if this has a simple answer.

I have been playing about with pgRouting and using Osm2pgrouting to load OSM files from Geofabrik.

However I just noticed that the OSM_id isn't being created by Osm2pgrouting.

I'm trying to exclude some roads in pgRouting that are tagged "motors=no" in OSM but can't because I can't match them without the osm_id field?